# Question regarding usage of array as a pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

For eg. I have an array of structs 'a' as below:

```
struct mystruct{
    int b
    int num;
};
struct bigger_struct {
   struct my_struct a[10];
}

struct bigger_struct *some_var;
```

i know that the name of an array when used as a value implicitly refers to the address of the first element of the array.(Which is how the array subscript operator works at-least)
Can i know do the other way around i.e 
if i  do:

`some_var->a->b`, it should be equivalent to `some_var->a[0]->b`, am i right? I have tested this and it seems to work , but is this semantically 100% correct?

Comment: 'some_var->a[0]->b' should be 'some_var->a[0].b'

Comment: @Keith You're using the wrong character for the code. It's a "[Grave Accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)" ```.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is `some_var->a->b` equivalent to `some_var->a[0]->b`?

No, it is equivalent to `some_var->a[0].b`.

The exact specification of the array-to-pointer conversion is actually quite straightforward:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
>   string  literal  used to  initialize  an  array, an expression  that  has  type  *array  of type* is converted to an expression with type *pointer to type* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue (C99 6.3.2.1).

`some_var->a` has the type `my_struct[10]`, which is an array type, and since it is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator and is not a string literal, it is converted to a pointer to the initial element of the array.

Comment: Yes i actually meant to write some_Var->a[0].b , i meant to ask are the two equivalent? Yes thanks for your reply,just the confirmation i needed!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have allocated memory for `some_var`, its safe to do `some_var->a->b` (as arrays decay into pointer).

Comment: Yes memory for some_var is allocated. OK thanks a ton,i just needed that confirmation

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `_var->a[0]->b` and `_var->a->b` are equivalent

Because `a[0]` and a  is representing the base address of the structure.